# Is it possible to /manipulate/ functions as it is strings?

Tags: javascript, function, semantics

```
var myString = '';
myString += 'foo';
myString += 'bar';
myString = myString.replace(/oba/, 'qux');

console.log(myString) // produces "foquxr"
```

Is there any way to likewise tinker around with functions, like, say, turning `function(a) { a += 'b'; return a; }` info `function(a) { a += 'b'; console.log(a); return a + 'c'; }`?

Comment: Sounds like you want to learn a lisp :).

Comment: can you show us what you've tried? how do you plan on altering the function? are you running into problems?

Comment: Either my coffee has not kicked in, or your question makes no sense. You want to change a function?

Comment: That is possible using `eval()`, but please don't do it, it's just wrong.

Comment: @AndrewAylett perhaps... I'm a more pragmatic guy and don't plan on getting super into compsci, but the more I hear and see abt it the more interesting it seems... the parens just seem so god awfully ugly, tho.

Comment: @jackwanders nope, it was a purely theoretical question meant only to further mine and others' understanding of the capabilities of the language. intellectual masturbation only.

Comment: @epascarello seems like the answer below managed it, though, I'm having some minor trouble wrapping my head around what he wrote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [compose](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition) functions thus

```
// (compose(f, g))(x, y, ...) is the same as f(g(x, y, ...)) 
function compose(f, g) {
  return function (var_args) {
    return f.call(this, g.apply(this, arguments));
  };
}
```

so

```
var f = compose(
  function (x) { console.log(x); return x + 'c'; },
  function (a) { a += 'b'; return a; });
```

lets you combine two small functions to get a function that behaves like

> ```
> function(a) { a += 'b'; console.log(a); return a + 'c'; }
> ```

Comment: Woaahhh, so confusing and trippy. Don't think I'll be using it in my code any time soon -- I still can't wrap my head around it just by reading your post. After a certain point of complexity, I just can't keep straight all the `a`s and `b`s and `c`s and `f`s and `g`s and `x`s.  I'm pretty sure it was what I was looking for though, and its not completely unuseful to me, because now i know that what I wwas imagining is possible and its very useful to know what the language you're using is capable of, even if you're not at the level of implementing those features yourself yet.

Comment: @adlwalrus, Function manipulation in JS depends a lot on the [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) and [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) methods.  Once you understand those, you can learn out everything else incrementally.

Comment: I understand both of those already.  Still, yours is VERY confusing... :S

Comment: @adwalrus, If you don't care about `this`, you could write it thus:  `function compose(f, g) { return function () { return f(g.apply(null, arguments)); } }`.  Do you understand the meaning of the function composition operator?  When f and g are functions, (f ∘ g) is a function such that (f ∘ g)(x) is (f(g(x))).  Once you understand that, my implementation is just a function that returns a function that uses `apply` to handle parameter lists that are more complicated than just `x`.

Comment: Ummm, I remember that from HS math class.  It's pronounced _of_, correct?  Could you rephrase it without the apply just to make it as simple as possible as an isolated demo case that doesn't necessarily need to handle more complicated inputs than a mere `x`?

Comment: @adwalrus, for a single input parameter, `function compose(f, g) { return function (x) { return f(g(x)); }; }`.  I think that you're right that "of" can be used for both function calling and function composition.

Comment: So in a way we're just nesting functions here, right? Also, in the statement `return f(g(x));`, both `f` and `g` are being immediately dereferenced, correct?

Comment: @adwalrus, I don't know what you mean by "immediately dereferenced."

Comment: I mean that as soon as the interpreter encounters those tokens in that statement, it turns `f` from a reference to the argument received by the `compose` to the equivalent of a literal function expression containing the value of what the pointer `f` refers to.

Comment: How is that? I don't see how that would work here... Sorry, I'm confused again.

Answer (score 2):

You could achieve this (without using `eval`) by getting the function's body from its declaration, manipulating it as needed, and redefining it by means of the `Function()` constructor:

```
function myFunction(a) { a += 'b'; return a; }

function changeFunction(){
    var func = window['myFunction'].toString();
    var body = func.substring(func.indexOf("{")+1, func.lastIndexOf("}"));
    body = body.replace("return a;", "console.log(a); return a + 'c';");
    window.myFunction = Function("a", body);
}​
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NCBuG/)

Comment: Alright, but super hacky. I didn't mean _manipulate it as a string_, I meant the equivalent for programmatically constructing and tinkering with functions.  See @MikeSamuel's answer above.